# Convert WordPress custom shortcodes to work in a different theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have exported pages from a WordPress website built with design themes template and imported them to a new one with a different theme (buddyboss).

The pages I have imported are not displaying as they have been built with custom shortcodes (design themes) not recognised by the new theme (buddyboss).

Is there a way to convert the shortcodes to work with the new (buddyboss) theme?

Comment: Copy the code that registers the shortcodes you need from the old theme to the new one. You might need to copy some CSS rules as well.

Answer (score 2):

Search the old theme for calls to `add_shortcode`([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)). The second parameter to `add_shortcode` should be a PHP function located somewhere in the theme. You will need to bring the function that is executed by the shortcode, along with any additional code that is relied on, into the new theme (ie: in `functions.php` in the theme).